# How do I combine a SELECT + WHERE query with an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql, select, insert, where-clause

I want to combine the two following queries, can anyone give me a idea how to do that?
(the `INSERT` query should run only if the `SELECT` query has a result)

**query no 1**:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO senders(
sender_id,
telephone,
)
VALUES ( 1, 0723355888)
```

**query no 2**:

```
SELECT student_name
FROM students
WHERE student_id =1
```

Comment: why u want to select 'student_name' if u r not inserting it into 'senders'.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO senders (sender_id, telephone)
SELECT student_id, student_telephone FROM students
WHERE student_id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

or if telefone is not a part of the students table, hard code it:
This works because if the query 0 rows, no insert is performed at all.

```
INSERT INTO senders (sender_id, telephone)
SELECT 1, 0723355888 FROM students
WHERE student_id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this query -

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO senders (sender_id, telephone)  
SELECT student_id as sender_id, telephone
FROM students
WHERE student_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO senders( sender_id, telephone) 
SELECT 1 as sender_id, 0723355888 as telephone 
FROM students WHERE student_id =1
```